# Sending mail using java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I trying to send mail from domain but getting some error.

### Code:

```
package SendingClass;

import java.util.*;  

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;

import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmail  
{  
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String host="chnmail.hcl.com";
    final String user="allwinjayson.m@hcl.com";
    final String password="*******";
    String to="allwinjayson.m@hcl.com";

    //Get the session object  
    Properties props = new Properties();  
    props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  


    //new
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
    {  
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
            {  
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
            }  
    });  


     //Compose the message  
    try 
    {  
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Praise the Lord");
        message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");

        //send the message  
         Transport.send(message);  
         System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  
    } 
    catch (MessagingException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
}
```

### Error:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:756)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
    at SendingClass.SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:63)
```

Comment: is the authentication mechanism supported by both client and server ? try to use the connect method without using the username and password

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to enable SSL/TLS before your server will allow you to login.  Set the property [`mail.smtp.ssl.enable`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.ssl.enable) or [`mail.smtp.starttls.enable`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.starttls.enable) to `true`, depending on the requirements of your server.

Also, you'll want to clean up some of these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: i added but getting error "javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: chnmail.hcl.com, port: 25;"

Answer (score -1):

Does this perform any better? This is a simplified example from one of my Java application, hope I did not introduce a copypaste syntax errors. It looks similar to your code but have few extra smtp props.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("mail.smtp.allow8bitmime", "true");
prop.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "60000");
prop.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "60000");
prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
prop.put("mail.smtp.from", "myname@gmail.com");

final String username = "myname";
final String pwd      = "mypwd";
Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return new PasswordAuthentication(username, pwd);
    }
  }
);

Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress( (String)prop.get("mail.smtp.from") ));
((MimeMessage)msg).setSubject("My email title ÅÄÖ", "UTF-8");
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("other@world.com", false));

Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
mbp1.setText("This is a body text ÅÄÖ", "UTF-8");
mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
msg.setContent(mp);

Transport tr = session.getTransport("smtp");
tr.connect();
tr.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
tr.close();
```

Comment: Explaining what the actual problem is would go further than a code dump.

Comment: @Makoto: yes it is a problem already explained in a question right? My answer is to give futher props examples to try it out. JavaMail is sometimes a black magic and I am not here to declare an ultimate answer, just food for programmers mind to try. My code has worked for few other parties. This is Stackoverflow after all.

Comment: My immediate preference would be an authoritative answer as to why one could get that specific error coming back as opposed to some code which should "just work" to get around the issue.  Fixing the problem is one thing, but *knowing* where the problem originated is more valuable in this context.  Hence, the code dump doesn't seem that valuable to me.  Someone else *might* find it worthwhile, but I'm not seeing the value.

Comment: @Makoto: noted your opinion thanks. Let the original poster see how it fits his/her scenario and give more information if problem does not go away. We may iteratively find a solution.